# ¿Cómo puedo incluir caracteres especiales en un RegEx para SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

Estimadxs, buen día, estoy en desconcierto sobre como incluir determinados caracteres en un `RegEx` para usarlos en un `PatIndex`. Actualmente, hago esto:

```
PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z0-9]%', REVERSE(cadena))
```

Actualmente eso me funciona como es debido, pero quisiera agregar símbolos como:

```
- -> guión medio
. -> punto
, -> coma
: -> dos puntos
; -> punto y coma 
? -> signo de pregunta
```

¿Cómo debería hacerlo? Es la primera vez que uso esta forma y quisiera terminar de entender como funciona: Estuve leyendo y la forma, si no me equivoco, debería ser:

```
^-\.,:;\?$
```

Por lo que debería quedar algo como esto:

```
PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z0-9^-\.,:;\?$]%', REVERSE(cadena))
```

¿Es correcto?

Comment: Ojo que `^` representa inicio de cadena, y `$` fin de cadena. Para lo demás, deberías buscar qué caracteres necesitás _escapar_. Dependiendo de dónde lo ubicás, `^` también es _no coincidencia_ con los caracteres que le pases.

Comment: Lo que necesito, es que inlcuya lo visto al principio más los caracteres especificados.

Comment: Por cierto, ¿SQL en general o _SQL Server_?

Comment: SQLServer, olvide añadilrlo en los tags @padaleiana

Comment: @padaleiana de hecho, `^` representa una negación en los patrones de SQL Server. T-SQL no maneja RegEx como tal.

Comment: Sí, @LuisCazares, acabo de [leerlo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51244009).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los patrones en SQL Server (o t-sql, mejor dicho) están más limitados que en RegEx. Para incluir los otros caracteres solo tienes que agregarlos junto a tus rangos. Te dejo un ejemplo para probar

```
DECLARE @Cadena varchar(1000) = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-.,:;?!@#$%^&*()';

WITH 
E(n) AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT TOP( LEN( @Cadena))
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n
    FROM E4
),
cteCadenas AS(
    SELECT n, SUBSTRING( @Cadena, n, 1) cadena
    FROM cteTally
)        
SELECT *, 
       PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z0-9-.,:;?^]%' , (cadena)) PatronCorrecto, 
       PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z0-9^-.,:;?]%' , (cadena)) PatronIncorrecto
FROM cteCadenas;
```

Es importante aclarar que el acento circunflejo (^) es usado como un marcador para excluir caracteres o rangos. Para que lo tome como caracter, es importante dejarlo al final del patrón a buscar.

Comment: ¿Por qué en el caso del `-`, tanto en **PatronCorrecto** como **PatronIncorrecto**, me figura en `0`? Puesto que sino mal entendí, en el caso de **PatronCorrecto** debería figurar **1** en vez de **0** ya que `^` está al final, ¿O me equivoco?

Comment: El guion lo toma también como una forma de establecer rangos. Si está en medio de otros dos caracteres que no formen parte de un rango también lo ignorará.

Comment: Perfecto, entonces debería dejarlo para el final para que lo tome. Muchísimas gracias por la explicación y por el tiempo que te tomaste